# How to reduce an array in swift based on some condition

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I need to know a good solution in Swift for the below problem I am facing.

I have an array of models declared as `var dataArray = [PlanModel]()`.

```
class PlanModel: {

var isPurchased:String?
var planName:String?
}
```

Now I get data from the server and I fill the `dataArray` with the models. The `dataArray` consists of 3 models. The value of models are:

Model 1:

```
isPurchased = "true"
planName = "Question"
```

Model 2:

```
isPurchased = "true"
planName = "Personal"
```

Model 3:

```
isPurchased = "false"
planName = "Full"
```

What I need is to reduce this array by checking if the plan is purchased by checking value of `isPurchased`. If it's true remove it from array, if its false, then keep that in the array.

Please tell me what would be the simpler and efficient way of doing this in Swift?

Comment: use `filter` https://www.raywenderlich.com/82599/swift-functional-programming-tutorial

Comment: What if `isPurchased` is `nil`? Or `""`? Why is that property an optional? Why is it a string and not a boolean?

Comment: Agree with Martin R, you should use a boolean type instead of a string if all its going to be is true or false

Comment: Martin R is absolutely Right ..... you should use a boolean type instead of string type

Comment: @MartinR is it possible that app crash if there is no objects in array and we use filter ? Once I faced issue

Comment: @MikeAlter: No. You can call filter on an empty array without problems.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for replay , possibly issue occurred due to threads , I mean multiple threads updating same array

Comment: Yes I agree with you guys. isPurchased should be boolean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `filter` function

```
var reducedArray = dataArray.filter {$0.isPurchased == "false"}
```

This will check each element of the `dataArray` and if the elements `isPurchased` is `"false"` it will keep it

Comment: Thank you @Fonix. Simple example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` with `contains` function

Model Class:

```
class PlanModel {

    var isPurchased:String?
    var planName:String?

    init(isPurchased:String?, planname:String?) {
        self.isPurchased = isPurchased
        self.planName = planname
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var plan = [PlanModel]()            
        plan.append(PlanModel(isPurchased: "true", planname: "Question"))
        plan.append(PlanModel(isPurchased: "true", planname: "Personal"))
        plan.append(PlanModel(isPurchased: "false", planname: "Full"))

        // Filter function
        plan = plan.filter {
            ($0.isPurchased?.contains("false"))!
        }
        print(plan.count)
        // 1
}
```

Comment: What advantage has `contains()` over `==`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a filtering function:

```
func notPurchased(planModel: PlanModel) -> Bool{
   return planModel.isPurchased == "false"
}
```

and use the Array filter function passing in your function

```
let filteredArray = dataArray.filter(notPurchased)
```

Answer (score 1):

After post my solution, let me tell you that it's better change isPurchased type from String to Bool.

And now...

```
class PlanModel 
{

    var isPurchased:String?
    var planName:String?
}

let p1: PlanModel = PlanModel()
p1.isPurchased = "true"
p1.planName = "Question"

let p2: PlanModel = PlanModel()
p2.isPurchased = "true"
p2.planName = "Personal"

let p3: PlanModel = PlanModel()
p3.isPurchased = "false"
p3.planName = "Full"

var plans: [PlanModel] = [ p1, p2, p3 ]

// Filter elements with `isPurchased` property
// set to `true`. As isPurchased is marked as an
// `Optional` type I check that it's not nil before
// process it
plans = plans.filter()
{ 
    guard let isPurchased = $0.isPurchased else 
    { 
        return false 
    } 

    return isPurchased == "true" 
}


plans.forEach()
{ 
    if let planName = $0.planName
    {
        print(planName)
    }
    else
    {
        print("unnamed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for removing the item from array itself if it meets certain condition you can do the following code:

```
dataArray = dataArray.filter({ $0.isPurchased == "False"})
```

i find this is one of the best approaches and i was using Swift 3

Now on the side note, i recommend using [structs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html) instead of classes for models

Comment: Not really the best approach. This will *crash* if more than one element is removed ...